# Incrementar valores de array asociativo en PHP usando sesiones

Tags: php

Verán tengo que crear una especie de carro de la compra para tienda online. Lo que no consigo entender es el funcionamiento para incrementar la cantidad de un producto para cuando un usuario repita escogiendo el mismo producto. Agradezco toda ayuda.

```html
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
 session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Ejercicio</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
  /* inicializo las variable que almacenan errores vacías para que no muestren el código php al usuario */
  $opcionErr = $productosErr = "";
  /* inicializo una variable booleana con valor positivo que usaré para validar el envío del formulario */
  $correcto = true;
  /* inicializo otra variable booleana con valor negativo que usaré para validar el envío del formulario */
  $terminarCompra = false;

  $_SESSION["carro"] = [
   "Leche semidesnatada" => 0,
   "Yogur natural" => 0,
   "Queso fresco" => 0,
   "Solomillo" => 0,
   "Lomo ibérico" => 0,
   "Chuleta de cerdo" => 0,
   "Salmón ahumado" => 0,
   "Sardina fresca" => 0,
   "Bacalao salado" => 0,
   "Jabón de manos" => 0,
   "Detergente" => 0,
   "Gel de baño" => 0,
   "Lechuga" => 0,
   "Calabacín" => 0,
   "Cebolla" => 0
  ];
  /* comprueba si el envío al servidor se hace con método post */
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   /* comprueba si la opción tiene el valor "seguir", en este caso se seguirá comprando */
   if ($_POST["opcion"] == "seguir") {
    /* comprueba si el valor del desplegable de los productos sea "selecciona", en este caso mostrará un mensaje de error y se da un valor negativo a la variable $correcto por tanto no se podrá enviar el formulario */
    if ($_POST["productos"] == "selecciona") {
     $productosErr = "Debe seleccionar algún producto antes de terminar la compra";
     $correcto = false;
    /*ESTA PARTE ES DONDE PIENSO QUE ESTA EL FALLO, NO CONSIGO QUE INCREMENTE LA CANTIDAD; 
    en caso contrario el usuario habrá seleccionado un producto del desplegable, se recorre el array carro hasta encontrar la coincidencia entre el producto seleccionado y un producto del array, cuando esto ocurra se incrementa la cantidad en 1 */
    } else {
     $productoSeleccionado = $_POST["productos"];
     foreach ($_SESSION["carro"] as $producto => $cantidad) {
      if ($productoSeleccionado == $producto) {
       $cantidad = $cantidad + 1;
       break;
      }
     }
    }
   /* comprueba si se ha seleccionado la opción con valor "terminar", en este caso se da un valor positivo a la variable $terminarCompra pudiendo ser enviado el formulario */
   } elseif ($_POST["opcion"] == "terminar") {
    $terminarCompra = true;
   /* comprueba si esta vacío el campo de las opciones, en este caso mostrará un mensaje de error */
   } elseif (empty($_POST["opcion"])) {
    $opcionErr = "Debe marcar una opción para poder continuar";
    $correcto = false;
   /* en cualquier caso no definido se da un valor negativo a la variable $correcto, haciendo imposible el envío del formulario */
   } else {
    $correcto = false;
   }
  }
  /* mientras alguna de las siguientes condiciones sean falsas se seguirá mostrando el formulario y el usuario seguirá eligiendo productos */
  if(!isset($_POST["botonEnvio"]) || !$correcto || !$terminarCompra) {
 ?>
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
  <label for="productos">Productos disponibles:</label>
  <select id="productos" name="productos">
   <option value="selecciona">- Selecciona -</option>
   <optgroup label="Lacteos">
    <option value="Leche semidesnatada">Leche semidestanada</option>
    <option value="Yogur natural">Yogur natural</option>
    <option value="Queso fresco">Queso fresco</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Carnes">
    <option value="Solomillo">Solomillo</option>
    <option value="Lomo ibérico">Lomo ibérico</option>
    <option value="Chuleta de cerdo">Chuleta de cerdo</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Pescados">
    <option value="Salmón ahumado">Salmón ahumado</option>
    <option value="Sardina fresca">Sardina fresca</option>
    <option value="Bacalao salado">Bacalao salado</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Limpieza">
    <option value="Jabón de manos">Jabón de manos</option>
    <option value="Detergente">Detergente</option>
    <option value="Gel de baño">Gel de baño</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Verduras">
    <option value="Lechuga">Lechuga</option>
    <option value="Calabacín">Calabacín</option>
    <option value="Cebolla">Cebolla</option>
   </optgroup>
  </select>
  <?php echo "* ". $productosErr; ?>
  <br><br>
  <label>Seguir comprando</label>
  <input type="radio" name="opcion" value="seguir">
  <br>
  <label>Terminar</label>
  <input type="radio" name="opcion" value="terminar">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="botonEnvio" value="enviar">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $opcionErr; ?></span>
 </form>
 <?php
  /* si no hay error y se envía el formulario correctamente se muestra por pantalla cada valor que ha guardado el array de sesión con nombre carro (los productos elegidos) */
  } else {
   /* bucle que recorre el array de sesión con nombre carro y va mostrando cada producto */
   foreach ($_SESSION["carro"] as $producto => $cantidad) {
    echo $producto ."=". $cantidad ."<br>";
   }
   /* cuenta los valores del array carro y si no tiene ningún valor es que esta vacío y muestra un mensaje indicandolo */
   if (count($_SESSION["carro"]) == 0) {
    echo "Su carrito esta vacío";
   }
   /* vacía el array carro */
   unset($_SESSION["carro"]);
   /* destruye la sesión */
   session_unset();
      session_destroy();
  }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

No se aumente el valor porque no asignas en ningún momento `$cantidad` en la clave dada del array.

Tampoco tienes que empezar a recorrer todo el array hasta encontrar el producto para aumentarle uno, puede verificar directamente si ese producto se encuentra en el array y entonces sumarle uno.

Esto se puede hacer en una sola línea, con un ternario:

```
isset ($_SESSION["carro"][$pSelected]) ? $_SESSION["carro"][$pSelected]+=1 : "";
```

Aquí `$pSelected` sería el valor que se busca. Usamos un ternario para determinar si ese valor está en el array, y si está le sumamos uno, si no está no hacemos nada.

Vamos a hacer algunas pruebas. Asignaré varios productos a la variable `$pSelected` usaré incluso valores erróneos:

```
$pSelected="Queso fresco";
isset ($_SESSION["carro"][$pSelected]) ? $_SESSION["carro"][$pSelected]+=1 : "";

$pSelected="fake";
isset ($_SESSION["carro"][$pSelected]) ? $_SESSION["carro"][$pSelected]+=1 : "";

$pSelected="Bacalao salado";
isset ($_SESSION["carro"][$pSelected]) ? $_SESSION["carro"][$pSelected]+=1 : "";

$pSelected="Queso fresco";
isset ($_SESSION["carro"][$pSelected]) ? $_SESSION["carro"][$pSelected]+=1 : "";

$pSelected="Queso fresco";
isset ($_SESSION["carro"][$pSelected]) ? $_SESSION["carro"][$pSelected]+=1 : "";
```

Veamos qué ha pasado (compramos tres quesos frescos y un bacalao)  y se intentó con un producto fake:

```
print_r($SESSION["carro"]);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [Leche semidesnatada] => 0
    [Yogur natural] => 0
    [Queso fresco] => 3
    [Solomillo] => 0
    [Lomo ibérico] => 0
    [Chuleta de cerdo] => 0
    [Salmón ahumado] => 0
    [Sardina fresca] => 0
    [Bacalao salado] => 1
    [Jabón de manos] => 0
    [Detergente] => 0
    [Gel de baño] => 0
    [Lechuga] => 0
    [Calabacín] => 0
    [Cebolla] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por tu respuesta A.Cedano, entiendo tu explicación. Aunque tras estar practicando he conseguido hacerlo de una forma distinta. Las modificaciones que hice fue establecer una variable y darle como valor el array de sesión e incrementar el valor con cada instancia en la que el usuario selecciona productos. Finalmente tras probar y probar comprobe que necesitaba añadir => $_SESSIO["carro"] = $carro para que se mantuviesen los productos seleccionados anteriormente sin esta parte de código solo me mostraba el último producto seleccionado sin almacenar los anteriores (Esta parte no la llego a comprender del todo bien).Finalmente el código modificado sería el siguiente:

```html
<?php
 error_reporting(0);
 session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Ejercicio 5.10.5</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
  /* inicializo las variable que almacenan errores vacías para que no muestren el código php al usuario */
  $opcionErr = $productosErr = "";
  /* inicializo una variable booleana con valor positivo que usaré para validar el envío del formulario */
  $correcto = true;
  /* inicializo otra variable booleana con valor negativo que usaré para validar el envío del formulario */
  $terminarCompra = false;
  /* comprueba si el envío al servidor se hace con método post */
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   /* comprueba si la opción tiene el valor "seguir", en este caso se seguirá comprando */
   if ($_POST["opcion"] == "seguir") {
    /* comprueba si el valor del desplegable de los productos sea "selecciona", en este caso mostrará un mensaje de error y se da un valor negativo a la variable $correcto por tanto no se podrá enviar el formulario */
    if ($_POST["productos"] == "selecciona") {
     $productosErr = "Debe seleccionar algún producto antes de terminar la compra";
     $correcto = false;
    /* en caso contrario el usuario habrá seleccionado un producto del desplegable, por lo tanto este producto se añade a un array de sesión con nombre carro */
    } else {
     /* variable que retiene el producto seleccionado por el usuario */
     $productoSeleccionado = $_POST["productos"];
     /* variable que retiene un array de sesión para el carro */
     $carro = $_SESSION["carro"];
     /* añado el producto seleccionado al carro (será la clave del array) y le sumo una unidad (cantidad que será el valor asociadoa  la clave) */
     $carro[$productoSeleccionado] = $carro[$productoSeleccionado] + 1;
     /* establezco la sesión para el carro sino no se mostraría nada */
     $_SESSION["carro"] = $carro;
    }
   /* comprueba si se ha seleccionado la opción con valor "terminar", en este caso se da un valor positivo a la variable $terminarCompra pudiendo ser enviado el formulario */
   } elseif ($_POST["opcion"] == "terminar") {
    $terminarCompra = true;
   /* comprueba si esta vacío el campo de las opciones, en este caso mostrará un mensaje de error */
   } elseif (empty($_POST["opcion"])) {
    $opcionErr = "Debe marcar una opción para poder continuar";
    $correcto = false;
   /* en cualquier caso no definido se da un valor negativo a la variable $correcto, haciendo imposible el envío del formulario */
   } else {
    $correcto = false;
   }
  }
  /* mientras alguna de las siguientes condiciones sean falsas se seguirá mostrando el formulario y el usuario seguirá eligiendo productos */
  if(!isset($_POST["botonEnvio"]) || !$correcto || !$terminarCompra) {
 ?>
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
  <label for="productos">Productos disponibles:</label>
  <select id="productos" name="productos">
   <option value="selecciona">- Selecciona -</option>
   <optgroup label="Lacteos">
    <option value="Leche semidesnatada">Leche semidestanada</option>
    <option value="Yogur natural">Yogur natural</option>
    <option value="Queso fresco">Queso fresco</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Carnes">
    <option value="Solomillo">Solomillo</option>
    <option value="Lomo ibérico">Lomo ibérico</option>
    <option value="Chuleta de cerdo">Chuleta de cerdo</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Pescados">
    <option value="Salmón ahumado">Salmón ahumado</option>
    <option value="Sardina fresca">Sardina fresca</option>
    <option value="Bacalao salado">Bacalao salado</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Limpieza">
    <option value="Jabón de manos">Jabón de manos</option>
    <option value="Detergente">Detergente</option>
    <option value="Gel de baño">Gel de baño</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="Verduras">
    <option value="Lechuga">Lechuga</option>
    <option value="Calabacín">Calabacín</option>
    <option value="Cebolla">Cebolla</option>
   </optgroup>
  </select>
  <?php echo "* ". $productosErr; ?>
  <br><br>
  <label>Seguir comprando</label>
  <input type="radio" name="opcion" value="seguir">
  <br>
  <label>Terminar</label>
  <input type="radio" name="opcion" value="terminar">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="botonEnvio" value="enviar">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $opcionErr; ?></span>
 </form>
 <?php
  /* si no hay error y se envía el formulario correctamente se muestra por pantalla cada valor que ha guardado el array de sesión con nombre carro (los productos elegidos) */
  } else {
   echo "La lista de los productos que están en el carro es la siguiente:<br>";
   print_r($_SESSION["carro"]);
   /* con el siguiente foreach también podría mostrar los pares de productos/cantidad almacenados*/
   /*foreach($_SESSION["carro"] as $producto => $cantidad) {
    if ($cantidad > 0){
     echo $producto ." - ". $cantidad."<br>";
    }
   }*/
   session_unset();
      session_destroy();
  }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo que dices ocurre porque 1º asignabas esto: `$carro = $_SESSION["carro"];` por tanto, lo que modificabas digamos así era una copia de la variable de sesión creada en `$carro` al hacer esto: `$carro[$productoSeleccionado] = $carro[$productoSeleccionado] + 1;`, por eso, tenías luego que *reasignar*  haciendo esto: `$_SESSION["carro"] = $carro;` Si desde un principio trabajases con la variable de sesión sin reasignar nada, sería más simple y menos confuso: `$_SESSION["carro"][$productoSeleccionado] = $_SESSION["carro"] + 1;` aunque no sé por qué menor no usas la forma que te sugerí.